# Specific game setup with Game Center

Tags: ios, game-center, multiplayer

Does anyone know a way to setup GKMatchRequest in a way that all players have the same properties? For the purposes of Game Center's auto-matching. `GKMatchRequest.playerAttributes` seems to be useless here.

A simple example would be: game allows you to pick couple of different maps, and you want to auto-match with other players that have picked the very same map.

Fallback solution is to have map voting after auto-matching, but that's something I'd like to avoid. Any thoughts? Appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but I've finally, accidentally found it. It's in  [GKMatchRequest documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchRequest_Ref/Reference/Reference.html). It seems GKMatchRequest.playerGroup provides the functionality I was looking for. Hope this will be of any help to anyone as poor at careful documentation reading as I am ;)